# Programming language to display different menu item based on user roles

Tags: javascript, php, xml, user-controls

What web-based programming language should I use to display different menu item based on the user roles in my application ?

For example, when the role "Staff" login, all menu items will be shown on the application but when the role "Agent" login, only part of the menu items will be shown.

In my opinion, I think it's easy to do it by using database and php to check if user is in the table. If yes, display related menu which is a bit "static". In this case, I guess I will have a lot .php files and long code.

Is there any method I can create a "dynamic" menu which should different menu based on user's roles ? I did some research and found XML might be the right one to use ? I'm not sure since I am new to programming.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it with some DB thinking and 30 rows of php. (Menù only)

Comment: In this case, isn't it still like a hard coded one ? Mind to explain a bit about your concept on how to do this ?

Comment: Well, you can always manage DB fields for that.

Comment: With two tables, one for what user can see and the other one for the menu items you can make a dynamic system.

Comment: That's actually what I was thinking but my supervisor said it's not dynamic if doing this way. haha.

Comment: @user3095178 LOL your supervisor isn't right and we (you and me) know this. That said an xml is slower than a Db Query (normally).

Comment: Thanks again, Goikiu. Is this the way that programmer always use to do access control ?

Comment: There are a lot of ways @user3095178 , you use them facing what system/menu you need.

Comment: So far, the only way i can think of is what you suggested. Do you mind to share few other ways ? Other ways term of programming language or method ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dynamic menu:

- create a table named "menu" with "link", "name" and "level" as fields;
- create a table named "users" with "name", "password", "level"
- make a call calling all the menus inside the menu table

IF the users level => than the level needed to show the menu, then show it; Otherwise don't.

To create new menus, just send them to the "menu" database with the corresponding fields needed.

Comment: Creating a table and not a Database Maybe?

Comment: Thanks. Based on my knowledge on programming so far, I think this is possible with only mysql and php, right ?